# Beginner's questions (figures, bibliography) with Sweave/R/LaTeX---my first document

Tags: r, latex, sweave, figure

I am just starting with `Sweave` and with `R`. Here I am using `R` to output some data and I am also trying to include a plot. The code does not sweave. I have one `Sweave` example from the web that compiles well in `RStudio` with `LaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=TRUE>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
xm <- mean(x)
xm
@

<<echo=FALSE>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
xm <- mean(x)
xm
@

<<echo=TRUE>>= 
test.frame<-read.table(file="apples.d",header=T,sep= "")
names(test.frame)
head(test.frame)
class(test.frame)
@
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\textwidth}
<<echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE,width=4,height=4>>=
plot(year,value)
@
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and the file apples.d contains:

```
#Number of apples I ate
year value
8   12050  #year 2008  
9   15292  #year 2009 
10  23907  #year 2010 
11  33997  #year 2011
```

What am I doing wrong?

Other related question:

Does a `Sweave` document support normal `LaTeX` `bibliography` file. How to do the compilation?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: You can do bibliography like in any LaTeX document. Remember, that between Sweave chunk's, it's "just" LaTeX code.

Comment: @Roman Thanks. This is good to know for a beginner. 1 vote up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several problems corrected, marked by %%%% or ####

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=TRUE>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
xm <- mean(x)
xm
@

<<echo=FALSE>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
xm <- mean(x)
xm
@

<<echo=TRUE>>= 
##### Remove all comments from your data file 
test.frame<-read.table(file="apples.d",header=T,sep= "")
names(test.frame)
head(test.frame)
class(test.frame)
@

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\textwidth}
<<echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE,width=4,height=4>>=
#### Must tell plot where to get the data from. Could also use test.frame$year
with(test.frame,plot(year,value))
@
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Dieter Thanks. The code works. Why do you ask to remove all comments from the date file? 1 vote up.

Comment: Because I assumed that # does not work in data files. Never done that before, and missed comment.char in the docs. Never trust assumptions....

Comment: Sweaving will add the `\usepackage{Sweave}` line, you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

Sweave does not take care of your bibliography, so you have to compile it by yourself; I believe some people have automated this job in their R scripts, but I would recommend you to use LyX if you are an experienced LaTeX user. LyX has official support to Sweave, and it takes care of everything you want in LaTeX intelligently (including bibliography). See the manual: https://github.com/downloads/yihui/lyx/sweave.pdf

Comment: Ok. So I can use BibTeX as usual to compile the document