# Figure numbers generated by Sweave/R and why only (PDF)LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, sweave, eps

I am continuing my earlier post here:

[Beginner's questions (figures, bibliography) with Sweave/R/LaTeX---my first document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337536/beginners-questions-figures-bibliography-with-sweave-r-latex-my-first-docu)

The working code is reproduced here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}  %%%%%%
\begin{document}
<<echo=TRUE>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
xm <- mean(x)
xm
@

<<echo=FALSE>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
xm <- mean(x)
xm
@

<<echo=TRUE>>= 
##### Remove all comments from your data file 
test.frame<-read.table(file="apples.d",header=T,sep= "")
names(test.frame)
head(test.frame)
class(test.frame)
@

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.5\textwidth}
<<echo=FALSE,fig=TRUE,width=4,height=4>>=
#### Must tell plot where to get the data from. Could also use test.frame$year
with(test.frame,plot(year,value))
@
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The above runs fine with `RStudio` (latest) and `Tinn-R` (latest) and the desired pdf document is produced.

Questions:

1. If I name the above file as `goodex.snw` and I run Sweave, I get the file `goodex-004.pdf` with either `Tinn-R` or `RStudio` as the PDF image of the plot. Why the trailing `004`? Can this be changed?
2. Can an `EPS` file be produced? Is the tool by which Sweave compiles to PDF is only through (PDF)LaTeX and not through the traditional DVI > PS > PDF route?
3. Just running the command `with(test.frame,plot(year,value))` in the `R` command window generates more values on the y-axis i.e. 15000, 20000, 25000 and 30000. However in the PDF file produced by Sweave by my code at the top of this post, I do not get all the values on the y-axis (only 15000 and 25000). How to control the size of the plot directly in the code so that all necessary y values appear?

---

Update: the file `apples.d` contains:

```
#Number of apples I ate
year value
8   12050  #year 2008  
9   15292  #year 2009 
10  23907  #year 2010 
11  33997  #year 2011
```

Comment: Your plot generation is not connected to Sweave or LaTeX. You need to sort that out in R (make a small, self-contained example in another question). Regarding Sweave, have you seen this? http://stat.epfl.ch/webdav/site/stat/shared/Regression/EPFL-Sweave-powerdot.pdf

Comment: @ Roman Thanks for this useful link.

Comment: @ Roman The plot generation is connected to Sweave in my understanding. I do explain what I get on the y-axis with R code (15000, 20000, 25000 300000) and while with Sweave I get only 15000 and 25000. I don't understand what it is so hard to understand here. 1 vote up

Comment: How can I include images here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible because we don't have the file `apples.d`, so we can only guess why the plot goes wrong. Please see:

[How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/567015)

on how to make a reproducible example.

Please note that `Sweave` is not a functionality of `Rstudio` or `Tinn-R`, it is an R function (`Sweave()`) that can be run from command line or with arguments from the R executable. This might be helpful to know if you are searching for information.

As for your questions:

1. The names of plots always have the form `FILENAME-CHUNKLABEL.pdf` or eps, where the chunk label can be set as option to the Sweave chunk (it's the first argument). If you don't set a chunk name the plots will be enumerated.
2. You can use `eps` with the option `eps=true`. I am pretty sure that by default both eps and pdf are produced though. As for compiling, Sweave does not compile by itself, it creates a `.tex` file that you can use in whatever way you want. In R 2.14 there is an option to run pdfLaTeX on the produced .tex file automatically,. The way `Rstudio` and `Tinn-R` compile is probably by using an pdfLaTeX call after Sweave. You can do it manually if you want to do it differently.
3. Without a reproducible example we can only guess. What is going wrong? You could set the limits of the plot with the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments but that shouldn't be what is going wrong here.

---

## Edit:

In response to edited question with data. First just a tip. This way of giving the data isn't the most useful way of doing it. We can of course reproduce this but it is much easier if you give the data in a way we can run immediately. e.g.:

```
test.frame<-data.frame(year=8:11, value= c(12050,15292,23907,33991))
```

As for the plot, you mean the labels on the y axis? This can be changed by omiting axes in the plot call and setting them manually with the `axis()` function:

```
with(test.frame,plot(year,value,axes=FALSE))
axis(1)
axis(2,test.frame$value,las=1)
```

This does look a bit weird if the ticks aren't constantly distributed over the axis though. Better would be:

```
with(test.frame,plot(year,value,axes=FALSE))
axis(1)
axis(2,seq(10000,35000,by=5000),las=1)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `eps = true` should be set in `\SweaveOpts{}`.

Comment: @ Sacha I have now put the contents of the file `apples.d`. Now you should be able to run the code.

Comment: `eps = TRUE` is a safer practice (or `T` if you really want to be lazy); `true` works only for historical compatibility

Comment: Updated the answer. Can't you set `eps=TRUE` in chunk options? Never really tried it out.